# Compile C packages on OSX 10.9

Tags: macos, go, cgo

With 10.9, compiling C packages in Go seems broken. When trying to build a package that ran on 10.8, clan outputs

```
clang: error: argument unused during compilation: '-fno-eliminate-unused-debug-types'
```

When I try to fix this up adding the following

```
#cgo CFLAGS: -Qunused-arguments
```

Go responds with

```
could not determine kind of name for C.<ctype>
```

for the imported types. Any hints how to solve this?

Comment: Do you use `pkg-config` pragma? When try to output `pkg-config --cflags --libs Foo`.

Comment: Yes I use `pkg-config`.

Comment: I don't think you're the first to run into this. Have a look at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-dev/H3FCUAlc6BU

Comment: did you reinstall the command line tools from ml?

Comment: Otherwise I would not have `clang`, would I? But yes, they're installed.

Comment: @ErikAigner, dumb suggestion: could you try `CC=clang go build`? I have the same problem right now and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known cgo bug ( probably http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=6515 )

You can download a 1.2 release candidate from https://code.google.com/p/go/downloads/list - as of 1.2rc2 this bug is claimed to be fixed.

Per comment 7 from the above bug report (if you don't want to use a release candidate):

> You can eliminate the option by editing the file src/cmd/cgo/gcc.go
>   and removing the option from the list of options--just search for it.